# PHP regex pattern validation with preg_match function always return false

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am testing following regex pattern with various possible values but I always get false. I am using PHP preg_match()

```
preg_match("/^[+0-9- ]{10, 12}$/","0812498915");
```

According to my knowledge, the output of this should be "true".

But it always returns "false"

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that unexpected result is I have unknowingly kept a space between the max, min values in the regex pattern.

```
preg_match("/^[+0-9- ]{10, 12}$/","0812498915");
```

Above syntax should be corrected as follows

```
preg_match("/^[+0-9- ]{10,12}$/","0812498915");
```

Removed space between 10 & 12